# TSQL lead/lag how to set it to NULL for each group

Tags: t-sql

I need to process overlap in/out dates so I have this code with Leadl/Lag which works perfectly, less that I need to process those values for each  group by CustID, so first ddStart for each CustID will have NULL in ***Lag***, and Last ddStart will have NULL in ***Lead***, in this example below it takes lead/lag values from another CustID, which I don't need.

Sorry this ***SOLVED:*** solution is below, didn't think about partioned.

```
CREATE TABLE cust (CustID int, DDStart date, DDEnd date )
--DROP table cust
INSERT INTO cust VALUES 
(111, '2012-01-01', '2012-01-31' ),
(222, '2014-08-01', '2014-08-31' ),
(222, '2014-09-01', '2014-09-30' ),
(222, '2014-10-01', '2014-12-31' ),
(333, '2016-08-01', '2016-08-31' ) 

SELECT  custID,   ddStart, ddEnd,
          '_' [_] ,
           LEAD (ddStart)  OVER (PARTITION BY custID ORDER BY custID, ddStart) ddStart_lead,
           LAG  (ddEnd)    OVER (PARTITION BY custID ORDER BY custID, ddStart) ddEnd_lag,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustID ORDER BY ddStart ) rn
 FROM cust
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry blank post, solved. In my manual i have example without partioned by,  using it solved this issue. Tx much all